# Log4j 2.11.1 JMS appender programmatically error

Tags: jms, log4j2, activemq-artemis, appender

I am trying to create a JMS appender using log4j 2.11.1 AND programmatically with Java (no properties file, sorry dudes) and ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.3. The problem is that it crashes and I get no data in my other appenders.

Does anyone have a working java JMS appender method? I am using this:

```java
private void addJmsAppender() {
        // LAYOUT
        LayoutComponentBuilder jmsLayout = builder.newLayout("SerializedLayout");
    // APPENDER
    AppenderComponentBuilder jmsAppender = builder.newAppender(jmsAppenderName, "JMS");
    jmsAppender.addAttribute("factoryBindingName", "ConnectionFactory");
    jmsAppender.addAttribute("factoryName", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    jmsAppender.add(jmsLayout);
    jmsAppender.addAttribute("name", jmsAppenderName);
    jmsAppender.addAttribute("providerURL", "tcp://localhost:61616");
    jmsAppender.addAttribute("destinationBindingName", "topic/loggertopic");

    builder.add(jmsAppender);
}
```

And these maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Required to capture mongo default log -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I am sorry but I don't even know how to get more data.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Could you please describe why it is necessary to use programmatic configuration? It's generally considered bad design to depend on the implementation details of a library rather than on the public API.

Comment: When you say "it crashes" what exactly does that mean? Is there any kind of error logged?

Comment: D.B.: I am using their public API following their public manual here https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html

Comment: 'It Crashes' means that 'Configurator.initialize(builder.build()); ', which usually starts my other working appenders (console, rolling and smtp) fails and the console appender used in the app from that moment is the safeguard I have in the log4j2.properties file. I now this because in the properties file this appender has a different layout.

Comment: @S.Traduct just because something is in the manual does not mean it's part of the public API. Please read the section titled [Log4j 2 API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html)

Comment: Thank you D.B., you are right. Now, back to the question I asked: can you help me REsolve the problem instead of dissolving it? It is clear that killing the patient finishes the illness but sometimes you just cannot do it.